# Easiest way to generate an undirected graph’s adjacency list?

Tags: algorithm, graph

The closest thing I could find was this:
https://csacademy.com/app/graph_editor/

But it doesn’t randomly generate a graph. I’m looking to generate an adjacency list for 1000+ node graph.

Ex. {0, 2, 3}, {1, 5}, ...

- Where Node 0 has edges 0, 2, 3
- Node 1 has edges 1,5
- And so on...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The algorithm for this is very simple, isn't it? For each `i`, for each `j` in `neighbours[i]`, add `(i,j)` to the edge set. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @kaya3 not exactly, the edge set is ordered so in the example I wrote, pretty much imagine a vector of vectors where the .at(0) contains a vector of every neighbor for node 0 etc etc

Comment: That's called an adjacency list; an edge set is just a set of all edges like `{(0,0), (0, 2), (0,3), ...}`. From the question it looks like you were describing the algorithm's input format, but if that's meant the be the output, what is the input?

Comment: Oh my mistake. As for the input, I just wanted a random graph generator where input is number of nodes and number of edges

Comment: I see. It would help if you made that clear in the question. What distribution do you want to generate graphs over? There are lots of different techniques for randomly generating graphs with certain statistical properties.

Comment: @kaya3 I will update the question. as for the distribution, I haven't really thought of that. I don't think it would matter for my specific use case though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [various models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_graph#Models) for generating random graphs with particular statistical properties. You've said in the comments that the distribution doesn't really matter for your use-case, so a simple model to use is the one which includes each potential edge with some fixed probability, independent of whether other edges are included. This distribution is usually called `G(n, p)` where `n` is the number of nodes, and `p` is the probability of an edge being included.

The algorithm to generate a graph from `G(n, p)` is straightforward:

- Initialise a graph with `n` nodes and no edges.
- For each (unordered/ordered) pair of nodes `u`, `v`:

  - Generate a random real number in the range [0, 1].
  - If this number is less than `p`, add the edge `u-v` to the graph.

The choice between unordered pairs and ordered pairs depends on whether you want an undirected or directed graph respectively.

Since you want an adjacency list, the "initialise" step will be to create a list containing `n` empty lists, and the "add edge" step will add `v` to `u`'s (and `u` to `v`'s list, if the graph should be undirected).

Here's an example implementation in Python:

```py
from random import random
from itertools import product, combinations

def random_graph(n, p, *, directed=False):
    nodes = range(n)
    adj_list = [[] for i in nodes]
    possible_edges = product(nodes, repeat=2) if directed else combinations(nodes, 2)
    for u, v in possible_edges:
        if random() < p:
            adj_list[u].append(v)
            if not directed:
                adj_list[v].append(u)
    return adj_list
```

Examples:

```py
>>> random_graph(4, 0.5)
[[1, 2, 3],
 [0, 3],
 [0],
 [0, 1]]
>>> random_graph(5, 0.25, directed=True)
[[0, 2, 4],
 [1, 4],
 [0, 1, 2, 3],
 [1],
 [1, 2]]
```

Comment: greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generate a random graph with `N` nodes and `M` edges, the easiest way is the following algorithm:

Let `list` be a list of all pairs `(0, 1)`, ...., `(0, N-1)`, `(1, 2)`, ...., `(N-2, N-1)`: all `S = (N - 1) * N / 2` possible edges. Then you need to generate a random subset of this list, with size `M`.

- Generate a random number `x0` from `0` to `S-1`
- Swap elements on indices `x0` and `S-1`
- Generate a random number `x1` from `0` to `S-2`
- Swap elements on indices `x1` and `S-2`
- (repeat until you generate `M` numbers)

Last `M` elements in the list will form a random subset of edges. Then you can just add them in your graph and create adjacency lists as you want.