# Random directed graph generation

Tags: python, algorithm, graph

I need to generate an adjacency list for a random directed graph with a number of nodes `n` and a number of edges `m`. I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60161376/easiest-way-to-generate-an-undirected-graph-s-adjacency-list), which is similar, but the edges exist or not based on probability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a similar algorithm as in [@kaya3's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60162325/5459839) on the question you linked to. Instead of taking a probability `p`, take the number of edges `m`, and instead of iterating all possible edges, take a `sample` of it of size `m`. Make those edges unconditionally.

The original code allowed loops to be generated (a node having an edge to itself) when `directed`. As you briefly commented you didn't want to have such loops, I added the corresponding `if` condition:

```
from random import sample
from itertools import product, combinations

def random_graph(n, m, *, directed=False):
    nodes = range(n)
    adj_list = [[] for i in nodes]
    possible_edges = product(nodes, repeat=2) if directed else combinations(nodes, 2)
    for u, v in sample(list(possible_edges), m):
        if u != v:  # added
            adj_list[u].append(v)
            if not directed:
                adj_list[v].append(u)
    return adj_list
```